# Tridion Sites 9.1 upgrade Publishing Deployment Processing Phase failed TridionUnzipStep

Tags: deployer, sites-9.1

All our publishing jobs are failing for some reason.  We see this Debug message in the logs, but no hard error message:

```
2020-11-13 10:20:47,537 DEBUG [http-nio2-8084-exec-7] LegacyStateXMLRenderer - Generated State XML for execution id tcm:0-1040981-66560 is: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<deployerTransaction processorId="25700@servername" transactionId="tcm:0-1040981-66560" started="true" startTime="2020-11-13T10:20:44.257-06:00" failed="true" endTime="2020-11-13T10:20:45.013-06:00" completed="false" currentStep="FinalizeStep">
    <stateFile>/uploads/binary/Binaries/tcm_0-1040981-66560.state.xml</stateFile>
    <PrepareStep id="PrepareStep" started="true" startTime="2020-11-13T10:20:44.483-06:00" failed="true" endTime="2020-11-13T10:20:44.987-06:00" completed="false">
        <UnzipLocation>NotAvailable</UnzipLocation>
        <Notification status="FAILED">Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed. Failed to execute pipelineId: 'Tridion-Bootstrap' for 'tcm:0-1040981-66560' because of No implementation found for step: TridionUnzipStep</Notification>
    </PrepareStep>
    <ProcessingStep waitForCommit="false" id="Processing" started="false" failed="false" completed="false">
        <TransactionLog>/uploads/binary/Binaries/Transaction/tcm_0-1040981-66560.translog</TransactionLog>
    </ProcessingStep>
    <PreFinalizeStep id="PreFinalizeStep" started="false" failed="false" completed="false">
        <UnzipLocation>NotAvailable</UnzipLocation>
    </PreFinalizeStep>
    <FinalizeStep id="FinalizeStep" started="false" failed="false" completed="false">
        <UnzipLocation>NotAvailable</UnzipLocation>
    </FinalizeStep>
</deployerTransaction>
```

And we see a popup warning message if we click on the Failed transaction in the Preparing Deployment phase of the transaction that reads "Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed. **Failed to execute pipelineId: 'Tridion-Bootstrap' for 'tcm:...' because of No implementation found for step: TridionUnzipStep**

As far as we can tell permissions are set up properly.  Tridion Support has said they can't find anything wrong with our config files

The TridionUnzipStep exists and looks normal.  We don't see anything unruly like nested comments or anything like that.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Welcome to Tridion stack exchange. Please let us know when you say you upgrade to Sites 9.1 . Did you upgrade from Sites 9.0 or lower please let us know From which version you are upgrading . Did you install  the deployer-combined services. Are you able to preview the page on the content manager . Are you using DXA.

Comment: We are upgrading from Web 8.5 to Sites 9.1.  We installed deployer-sites-combined.  We are able to preview - that's an excellent thought to check on that, though.  And no, we are not using DXA.

Comment: Please refer to the  link on the answer below.

Comment: kromaak , let us know if you are facing the issue

Comment: Are you using an add-on service? if yes Are there any extensions uploaded to the add-on service?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following reference [link1](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000011717) and  [link2](https://gateway.sdl.com/CommunityKnowledge?articleName=000012247)

Hope it Helps.